# GWT ConfirmMessageBox

Tags: java, gwt, messagebox, dialog

I need some kind of ConfirmMessageBox for an gwt implementation. Is there something prepared for this from gwt, or is the only way to do that to extend dialog boxes ?

the basic idea is a box with the question "Do you want to save this current state?" and 2 buttons "YES" (saves data) and "NO" (rejects data).

Thanks for any help or new ideas

Answer (score 1):

No ready-to-use implementation from my recall. You can try Ext_GWT. However, it won't be complex to do it by your own, extending the DialogBox and adding two buttons, and that's how I did it.

Answer (score 1):

other than `extends DialogBox` there is no other option .You can manage it by handling `panel with masking`(Making custom css) ,But its become more mess than extending `DialogBox`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out `Window.confirm(String message)` which returns a boolean to indicate OK/Cancel